# get order id in Observer on sales_order_invoice_save_after

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, event-observer, invoice

I want order id in observe function but I am getting null
I am using this code 
**Observe.php**

```
public function invoiceexport(Varien_Event_Observer $event=null){
    $_helper = Mage::helper('Nino_invoiceexport');
    $importStartDateTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $orders = $event->getOrder();
    print_r($orders);
    die;
}
```

My **config.xml** is as :

```
<events>
    <sales_order_invoice_save_after>
         <observers>
             <Nino_invoiceexport_order_invoice_save_after>
                  <type>singleton</type>
                  <class>Nino_InvoiceExport_Model_Observer</class>
                  <method>invoiceexport</method>
              </Nino_invoiceexport_order_invoice_save_after>
          </observers>
     </sales_order_invoice_save_after>
</events>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get `orderId` by using this way,

```
    $invoice = $observer->getEvent()->getInvoice();
    $order = $invoice->getOrder();
    $orderId=$order->getId();
```

Comment: thanks Keyur one more things t want a customer id. how can i get this.

Comment: `$order->getCustomerId()` it will return if customer is exist in your webshop @Piyush